# WSO2 ESB Proxy Basic Service Chaining

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

this is what I thought would be a fairly straight-forward service chaining scenario.

All I want to do it forward some data to a proxy service, that proxy service will then iterate over the data and use an ID ("entity_id") from that data (which it can successfully retrieve) to look up a resource sitting in WSO2 Data Services Server. Once it has the result of that request, I want to forward it to another application (RequestBin, in this case).

Please take a look at my proxy configuration below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="pollService"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>   
         <iterate id="iter1"
                  expression="//*[local-name()='Change']"
                  sequential="true">
            <target sequence="anon">
               <sequence>
                  <log level="full"/>
                  <property name="uri.var.entityid" expression="//*[local-name()='entity_id']"/>
                  <call>
                     <endpoint>
                        <http method="get"
                              uri-template="http://54.66.155.36:9764/services/civicrm/activity/{uri.var.entityid}"/>
                     </endpoint>
                  </call>
                  <log level="full"/>
                  <call>
                     <endpoint>
                        <http method="post" uri-template="http://requestb.in/1c79v711"/>
                     </endpoint>
                  </call>
                  <log level="full"/>
               </sequence>
            </target>
         </iterate>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

I currently do not get any indication that those two calls have fired at all.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can enable the wirelog and verify whether calls have fired or not.
please refer the following blog post to learn about wirelog.

1 http://mytecheye.blogspot.in/2013/09/wso2-esb-all-about-wire-logs.html

Answer (score 0):

Could you also give a sample message (what is going into the proxy) , and to see a finer-grain detail of what is going on in your proxy , go into [esb-home]/repository/conf/ and open the log4j.properties file , and set
log4j.category.org.apache.synapse=DEBUG , also do as @robin suggested. Try putting

```
 <log level="full" category="DEBUG" separator="-----:-----"/>
```

in your proxy where you want to see the state of the message at that point.